# map-reduce jobs failed with virtual memory beyond limit in Yarn cluster

Tags: memory, mapreduce, virtual, hadoop-yarn

I get following error, while running a MapReduce job in YARN cluster:

```
Application application_1394582929977_164223 failed 2 times 
due to AM Container for appattempt_1394582929977_164223_000002 exited with exitCode: 143 
due to: Container [pid=28402,containerID=container_1394582929977_164223_02_000001] is running beyond virtual memory limits. 
Current usage: 2.5 GB of 5 GB physical memory used; 10.5 GB of 10.5 GB virtual memory used. 
Killing container.
```

2.5 GB of 5 GB physical memory is used. However, all of the virtual memory gets used. How can I override the virtual memory settings, to increase it for my job or analyse my job to figure out why so much of virtual memory is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Search for 
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled